# Web Essentials is opening bundle file on every build, how to turn it off

Tags: bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

I have installed “Web Essentials 2013 nightly”. I am using it to bundle JavaScript files.
Every time I compile my project in Visual Studio the js.bundle file get focused in Solution Explorer and file is opened in code editor.
How to turn it off?
I am using VS 2013 Update RC2
I tried to configure it in
 Tools - options
Web Wssential -Javascript - Bundle (Run on build = false) but it dosn't work

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears to have been fixed with the latest build of Web Essentials.